# Transparent Screen Selection

Tags: wireless, camera, silkscreen, ideas

We are as a team with four members intending to design an augmented reality oriented smart glass which shall contain a CMOS camera, wireless communication and transparent screen. The algorithm below as flow diagram.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2Iuuy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The main problem we are having is to find a transparent display fitted into project (2"-2.5 is reasonable for smart glass.) My question is what else can be done instead of transparent display? Are there really fitted displays that we missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do AR by simply placing a "transparent screen" over someone's eyes — the screen will be horribly out of focus.

There are two possible approaches that are commonly used:

- Use a VR (non-transparent) display, but mix the image from your camera in with the picture elements generated by the augmentation software.
- Use an optical beam splitter along with an ordinary non-transparent display. Between the display and the beam splitter, you have optics that cause the display to appear much farther away than it actually is, so that the user can focus on both the real world and the display at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I think putting one beam splitter for each eye shall provide good resolution.